# Markers on seaborn line plot in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

New here so putting hyperlinks. My dataframe looks like this.

```
 HR     ICULOS  SepsisLabel PatientID
100.3      1         0          1
117.0      2         0          1
103.9      3         0          1
104.7      4         0          1
102.0      5         0          1
88.1       6         0          1
```

Access the whole file [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Am1j7gBl276r-Swj0EYA4tWSR_FH?e=EdHzxf). What I wanted is to add a marker on the HR graph based on SepsisLabel (See the file). E.g., at ICULOS = 249, Sepsis Label changed from 0 to 1. I wanted to show that at this point on graph, sepsis label changed. I was able to calculate the position using this code:

```
mark = dummy.loc[dummy['SepsisLabel'] == 1, 'ICULOS'].iloc[0]
print("The ICULOS where SepsisLabel changes from 0 to 1 is:", mark)
Output: The ICULOS where SepsisLabel changes from 0 to 1 is: 249
```

I Plotted the graph using the code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))

ax = plt.gca()

ax.set_title("Patient ID = 1")
ax.set_xlabel('ICULOS')
ax.set_ylabel('HR Readings')
sns.lineplot(ax=ax, 
             x="ICULOS", 
             y="HR", 
             data=dummy, 
             marker = '^', 
             markersize=5, 
             markeredgewidth=1, 
             markeredgecolor='black', 
             markevery=mark)

plt.show()
```

This is what I got: [Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y32FP.png). The marker was supposed to be on position 249 only. But it is also on position 0. Why is it happening? Can someone help me out?

Thanks.

Comment: You could try `markevery=[mark]` to give a list of positions to mark.  `markevery=249` would set a marker every 249 positions, starting with position 0.

Comment: Great. Is it possible to add the number(mark) above/below the marker on the graph?

Comment: Got the error using this

Comment: Other error then some typos? `ax.text(mark, dummy.loc[mark, 'HR'], str(dummy.loc[mark, 'ICULOS']) + '\n', ha='center', va='center')`? Can you solve them?

Comment: Typos errors. Now it's done. Can you please briefly explain what this code did?

Comment: Also, the mark should be on 249, but was on 250. So, I did:
 `ax.text(mark-1, dummy.loc[mark-1, 'HR'], str(dummy.loc[mark-1, 'ICULOS']) + '\n', ha='center', va='center')`  I don't know why but it worked.

Comment: Also, this code ax.... is valid only for this example only. When I try to run it with other data (same data, different patient), I got key error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working with `markevery` can be tricky in this case, as it strongly depends on there being exactly one entry for each patient and each `ICULOS`.

Here is an alternative approach, using an explicit scatter plot to draw the marker:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'HR': np.random.randn(200).cumsum() + 60,
                   'ICULOS': np.tile(np.arange(1, 101), 2),
                   'SepsisLabel': np.random.binomial(2, 0.05, 200),
                   'PatientID': np.repeat([1, 2], 100)})
for patient_id in [1, 2]:
    dummy = df[df['PatientID'] == patient_id]
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 6))
    ax.set_title(f"Patient ID = {patient_id}")
    ax.set_xlabel('ICULOS')
    ax.set_ylabel('HR Readings')
    sns.lineplot(ax=ax,
                 x="ICULOS",
                 y="HR",
                 data=dummy)
    x = dummy[dummy['SepsisLabel'] == 1]["ICULOS"].values[0]
    y = dummy[dummy['SepsisLabel'] == 1]["HR"].values[0]
    ax.scatter(x=x,
               y=y,
               marker='^',
               s=5,
               linewidth=1,
               edgecolor='black')
    ax.text(x, y, str(x) + '\n', ha='center', va='center', color='red')
    plt.show()
```

[image: marking a point on an sns.lineplot]

For your new question, here is an example how to convert the 'ICULOS' column to pandas dates.  The example uses date `20210101` to correspond with `ICULOS == 1`. You probably have a different starting date for each patient.

```py
df_fb = pd.DataFrame()
df_fb['Y'] = df['HR']
df_fb['DS'] = pd.to_datetime('20210101') + pd.to_timedelta(df['ICULOS'] - 1, unit='D')
```

Comment: Solved my problem. Thnx :)

Comment: It is a time series data, but I don't have date information. Can I convert ICULOS to date time format? So, I can run Fbprophet algorithm?

Comment: With the [datetime](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/dates_api.html) functions you could use the ICULOS as timedelta to be added to the start date.

Comment: How? I tried:
`df_fb = df_8[['ICULOS', 'HR']].copy()`
`df_fb.rename(columns = {'ICULOS':'DS'}, inplace = True)`
`df_fb.rename(columns = {'HR':'Y'}, inplace = True)`
`DS Y` 
`1 100.3`

Then I did 
`df_fb['DS'] = pd.to_datetime(df_fb['DS'])`

This produced:

`0 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001 100.3`

Comment: I updated the answer with an example of how the ICULOS could be converted to dates.